# Fetch list of data flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I just want to fetch the whole list of my model and in my response>

I cannot assign the result of the HTTP request to the list. Could anybody provide me what I'm missing in my code?

I want to fetch the whole list of 20 items as count param says but I'm getting a single response.body and it is not possible to assign it to a list which I expect. How to convert it to a list?

My error: Cannot assinge Future to Future<List>

Base response:

```dart
class ApiService {
  String baseUrl = astronomyApiUrl;

  Future<http.Response> fetchData(Map<String, String> urlParams) async {
    http.Response response;
    var combinedUrl = combineUrl(urlParams: urlParams);

    final url = Uri.parse(combinedUrl);
    try {
      response = await http.get(url);
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
    return response;
  }

  String combineUrl({Map<String, String>? urlParams}) {
    final buffer = StringBuffer();
    urlParams!.forEach((name, value) {
      buffer.write("$name=$value&");
    });

    return "$baseUrl/api/?${buffer.toString()}";
  }
}
```

List response:

```dart
class AstronomyService {
  Future<List<AstronomyModel>?> getAstronomy() async {
    try {
      final response = await ApiService().fetchData({
        "thumbs": true.toString(),
        "count": "20",
      });

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final result = astronomyModelFromJson(response.body);
        return result; //Cannot assinge Future<AstronomyModel> to Future<List<AstronomyModel>>
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } on SocketException catch (e) {
      throw e;
    } on HttpException catch (e) {
      throw e;
    } on FormatException catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
}
```

Model:

```dart
AstronomyModel astronomyModelFromJson(String str) =>
    AstronomyModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

class AstronomyModel {
  AstronomyPicModel({
    this.date,
    this.hdurl,
    this.description,
    this.mediaType,
    this.thumbnailUrl,
    this.title,
    this.url,
  });

  DateTime? date;
  String? hdurl;
  String? description;
  String? mediaType;
  String? thumbnailUrl;
  String? title;
  String? url;

  factory AstronomyModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      AstronomyModel(
        date: DateTime.parse(json["date"]),
        hdurl: json["hdurl"],
        description: json["description"],
        mediaType: json["media_type"],
        thumbnailUrl: json["thumbnail_url"],
        title: json["title"],
        url: json["url"],
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `AstronomyModel.fromJson` just creates a single `AstronomyModel`.

So your `astronomyModelFromJson(response.body)` will just create a single one too.

As you provide no indication as to what the API is, or what the response.body is, this is just a guess:

Assuming that API call does return a list (why don't you look at it, and print it out?  `print(response.body);`), then perhaps what you want to do is something like:

`final result = response.body.map((a)=> astronomyModelFromJson(a));`

Answer (score 0):

I messed up in model part. I was decoding just single response instead of list.

Solution was just to replace this:

```dart
AstronomyModel astronomyModelFromJson(String str) =>
    AstronomyModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));
```

To this:

```dart
List<AstronomyModel> astronomyModelFromJson(String str) => List<AstronomyModel>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => AstronomyModel.fromJson(x)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are having this issue because astronomyModelFromJson method will return you AstronomyModel while the Future is waiting to return List. You should try doing something like this

```dart
   class AstronomyService {
 Future<List<AstronomyModel>?> getAstronomy() async {
   try {
     final response = await ApiService().fetchData({
       "thumbs": true.toString(),
       "count": "20",
     });

     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
       final items = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
       List<AstronomyModel> result = items.map<AstronomyModel>((json) {
       return AstronomyModel.fromJson(json);
     }).toList();
     return result;
     } else {
       return null;
     }
   } on SocketException catch (e) {
     throw e;
   } on HttpException catch (e) {
     throw e;
   } on FormatException catch (e) {
     throw e;
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 try {
      final response = await ApiService().fetchData({
        ListView.builder(
                    itemCount:20           
      });
```

.try list view builder instead may be it works and try to initialize

```
List<AstronomyModel>
```

.on your screen may be it works.
thanks